# How to write piano program in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, bgi

I am trying to write a C program for piano in which the node of piano is controlled by mouse movement. But as in linux #include<dos.h> and #include<conio.h> is not exist, so i am getting error . Is there any alternative library present in linux for #include<conio.h> and #include<dos.h> ?
I have tried the code following.

```
#include <dos.h>
#include <graphics.h>
union REGS in, out;

void detect_mouse ()
{
    in.x.ax = 0;
    int86 (0X33,&in,&out);   //invoke interrupt
    if (out.x.ax == 0)
        printf ("\nMouse Failed To Initialize");
    else
        printf ("\nMouse was Succesfully Initialized");
}

void showmouse_graphics ()
{
    int gdriver = DETECT, gmode, errorcode;
    initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "c:\\tc\\bgi");
    in.x.ax = 1;
    int86 (0X33,&in,&out);
    getch ();
    closegraph ();
}
void detect ()
{
    int button;
    while (!kbhit () )
    {
        in.x.ax = 3;
        int86 (0X33,&in,&out);
        button=out.x.bx&7
        switch(button)
        {
            case 1:
                print(“left button pressed\n”);
            break;
            case 2:
                print(“right button pressed\n”);
            break;
            case 4:
                print(“middle button pressed\n”);
            break;
            case 3:
                print(“left and right button pressed\n”);
            break;
            case 5:
                print(“left and middle button pressed\n”);
            break;
            case 6:
                print(“right and middle button pressed\n”);
            break;
            case 7:
                print(“all the three buttons pressed\n”);
            break;
            default:
                print(“No button pressed\n”);
        }
        delay (200); // Otherwise due to quick computer response 100s of words will get print
    }
}
void hide_mouse ()
{
    in.x.ax = 2;
    int86 (0X33,&in,&out);
}

int main ()
{
    detect_mouse ();
    showmouse_graphics ();
    detect ();
    hide_mouse ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is ancient Borland Turbo C code shown, these days you can't use graphics like that unless you have a simulator to run it in. The old DOS interrupts won't work either, outside of a simulator, because Linux is not MS-DOS. You might consider using `termios`, please see [Mouse event handling in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233626/mouse-event-handling-in-linux)

Answer (score 3):

For `#include<conio.h>` you can use `#include <curses.h>` which will give you almost all the functionalities. [Getchar](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/scanw.html#GETCHCLASS)

For `#include<dos.h>` it's not usable in any other operating system than DOS and there isn't really something similar with all the functionalities in linux. But you can use `usleep(microseconds)` in linux when you include `#include <unistd.h>`.

Or you can use sleep_for in c++:

```
using namespace std::this_thread; // sleep_for, sleep_until
using namespace std::chrono; // nanoseconds, system_clock, seconds
sleep_for(nanoseconds(20));
```

For Generating Sound, it seems that this post tries to do something similar/could help with your problem:

[Generate Sound Frequency using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678470/generating-sound-of-a-particular-frequency-using-gcc-in-ubuntu)

Comment: #include<dos.h> is needed for sound generation in piano. is there any alternative function which can generate the sound in linux?  there is several function like interrupt function     int86 (0X33,&in,&out) will not work except #include<dos.h> . How to resolve that kindly help me